# Hibernate @ManyToOne Cascade Mix

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Recently I've been developing a base project and came across a scenario. Let's say I have a `School` with a list of `User`s that might have a new or an existing address, as the following mapping:

```
@Table("school") @Entity
class School {
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="school")
    private List<User> students;
}

@Table("user") @Entity
class User {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(...)
    private School school;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=?)
    @JoinColumn(...)
    private Address address;
}

@Table("address") @Entity
class Address { ... } // No bi-directional relationship
```

Whenever I try to persist I got the outputs:

1. If the `School` has only `User`s with a new address and the cascade type is set to `ALL` or `PERSIST`, saving a new instance of `School` works as expected.
2. If the `School` has only `User`s with existing address and the cascade type omitted, it works as expected when saving a new `School`.
3. When saving a new instance of `School` containing `User`s  with new and existing address and the CascadeType is set to `ALL`, the following exception is thrown `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist`.(I understand because the list has saved address)
4. When saving a instance of `School` with mixed `User`s having new and existing address but no cascade type set, a transient exception is thrown, as expected.

I wonder if there's a solution other than saving every user address before saving `School` object.

Comment: Cascade is really meant for the `@OneToMany` side of a relationship. I'd say it makes most sense to ensure all Addresses are persisted first. Personally I think it's poor form to use Cascade annotations at all. I suppose they seem convenient but I don't like not being in full control of database access since it can impact performance significantly if not handled carefully.

Comment: The questions are: 1. how do you "save" and 2. where do the existing objects come from? Are they loaded in the same transaction? Are you using Spring Data JPA or plain JPA Entity Manager or Hibernate Session. Please give me some more context.

Comment: 1) I'm using Spring Data Repository `save` method. 2) For the sake of simplicity, assume it comes in a detached fashion. I've set up a Spring Boot with Spring Data as persistent layer. The question comes down to how cascade is propagated.